# jQuery Template - Reverse Templating

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

So i'm working on a document system with a templating feature built in.  On one page you will create your template with 'tags' using the jQuery templating markup:

```
${RestaurantName}
${ContactName}
```

Then on the documents page you would choose the template to use and then it would convert your tags into HTML markup.  The documents page uses CKEditor for the WYSIWYG editing.  Right now I have it so that when the template is rendered it will look like:

```
<span class="RestaurantName">Ruby Tuesdays</span>
<span class="ContactName">Bob Smith</span>
```

The idea is before I send the document back to the database to save I would like to convert my  back in to template tags so that if the data is updated on the site somewhere else it will also be updated when the page is rendered again.

Any help or pointers on how I could accomplish this would be a huge help.  Thank you!

Comment: How are the data before sending to the server?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to think about getting the data from the DOM instead of "reverse templating". Look into `$.link()` (jQuery 1.4.3) or use the `jeditable` plugin to update element data on the fly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I don't think jeditable will be helpful in this situation because it is a textarea. But I will look in to the $.link() method!

Comment: Also, you might try rendering items in your template with ID attributes as opposed or in addition to CLASS attributes.  With IDs, you can just call the exact element like so $('#id').val() to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

Through some help on the StackOverFlow chat room I was able to figure out how to convert the above text:

```
var editorText = ckeditor.ckeditorGet().getData(), temp = $('<div />').append(editorText);

$.each(templateTags, function(name, val){
    temp.find('span.'+name).after('{{html '+name+'}}').remove(); 
}); 

console.log(temp.html());
```